# Get the number of arguments passed to a method with an unknown number of arguments

Tags: java, arguments, iteration

I'm creating a method:

```
private boolean method(String... arguments){
   for (String argument : arguments) {
     ...
   }
   return true;
}
```

I'd like to know how many arguments are passed to my method.

Is there is a clean way of doing this, instead of just creating a method that would iterate each argument and count them one by one?

My aim would be to return false if the number of arguments passed to my method is odd.

Comment: a vararg is converted to an array, so `arguments.length` would work

Comment: technically, you are only passing one parameter, being an array of String objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

var-args are converted to array, so you can use `.length` on it:

```
arguments.length; // length of arguments
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know how this way of passing arguments is called?

Comment: @Nofix Simply using `methodName(t1)` , `methodName(t1, t2)` or even `methodName()` would work fine.

Comment: @Nofix You can read more about it at **[this link](https://www.javatpoint.com/varargs)**